# Can I Use Sprite For Google Map's Groundoverlay?

Tags: flash, google-maps

(using flash)
I have a Sprite object that I want to show on google map. So I made a GroundOverlay object using my Sprite object, but it doesn't show up. I guess it's because Sprite is higher class than DisplayObject. (GroundOverlay seems getting DisplayObject only..?) Is there any way to us Sprite for my GroundOverlay? or alternative idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this code from this website, I don't remember the exact link but you can try, it almost what you want to do...

```
package
```

{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import com.google.maps.*;

```
public class sample extends Sprite
{
               private var polyLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();
               private var mapLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();
               private var map:Map = new Map();
               private var center:LatLng = new LatLng(36.469889,-93.949641);

               private var state:String = "39.108751,-94.586848 35.160337,-90.049495 35.474091,-97.520198";

               public function sample()
               {
                               addChild(mapLayer);
                               addChild(polyLayer);
                               map.key = "*** HERE YOUR API KEY ***";
                               map.sensor = 'false';
                               map.setSize(new Point(800, 600));
                               map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, function(event:MapEvent) {
                                               map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
                                               map.setMapType(MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
                                               map.setCenter(center, 6);
                                               redrawPolygons();
                               });

                               map.addEventListener(MapZoomEvent.ZOOM_CHANGED, function(event:MapZoomEvent) {
                                               redrawPolygons();
                               });

                               map.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.DRAG_STEP, function(event:MapMouseEvent) {
                                               redrawPolygons();
                               });

                               mapLayer.addChild(map);
               }


               private function redrawPolygons():void
               {
                               polyLayer.graphics.clear();
                               polyLayer.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000,0.8);
                               polyLayer.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000,0.5);
                               var coo:Array = state.split(" ");
                               for (var g=0; g<coo.length; g++) {
                                               var latlon:LatLng = LatLng.fromUrlValue(coo[g]);
                                               if (g==0) 
                                                    polyLayer.graphics.moveTo(map.fromLatLngToViewport(latlon).x, map.fromLatLngToViewport(latlon).y);
                                               else
                                                    polyLayer.graphics.lineTo(map.fromLatLngToViewport(latlon).x, map.fromLatLngToViewport(latlon).y);
                               }

                               polyLayer.graphics.endFill();
               }
}
```

}

Comment: I was so stupid... The reason my sprite doesn't show up was due to latlng values out of range :(